# Efficient Implementation of resistance distance for graphs?

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

Is there an implementation of the [resistance distance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_distance) (or just resistance matrix) for graphs available in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the definition from the Wikipedia article, this should give you the resistance distance matrix of the graph `g`:

```
With[{Γ = PseudoInverse[KirchhoffMatrix[g]]},
 Outer[Plus, Diagonal[Γ], Diagonal[Γ]] - Γ - Transpose[Γ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Jan Mangaldan created a resource function named [ResistanceMatrix](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ResistanceMatrix/) in 2023-12.
This is based on 2012rcampion's answer.

```wl
GraphResistanceMatrix[g_?GraphQ] := 
 Module[{kirchhoffMatrix, pseudoInverse, diagonal}, 
  kirchhoffMatrix = KirchhoffMatrix[g]; 
  pseudoInverse = PseudoInverse[kirchhoffMatrix];
  diagonal = Diagonal[pseudoInverse];
  SparseArray[
   Outer[Plus, diagonal, diagonal] - pseudoInverse - 
    Transpose[pseudoInverse]]]
```

To test this I did

```wl
data = EntityValue[
  FilteredEntityClass["Graph", 
   EntityFunction[graph, graph["VertexCount"] === 21]], 
  "ResistanceMatrix", "NonMissingEntityAssociation"]
```

[image]

Then I did

```wl
CheckResistanceMatrix = GraphResistanceMatrix[Graph[#1]] === #2 &;
```

Then I did

```wl
KeyValueMap[CheckResistanceMatrix][data]
```

and all the values from GraphResistanceMatrix matched GraphData's precomputed "ResistanceMatrix" value.